# Trying to restore backup for version 14.0.0.7105

Tags: 2010, powershell, backup, restore

We've been given a SP2010 backup (.bak) file to restore. At this time I don't know if it contains a site collection or a site or a farm, or how it was generated, and have no way to find out (just don't ask...).

Using PowerShell, I tried

> Restore-SPSite -path foo.bak -identity http://example.com -force

but I'm getting the following error:

> Restore-SPSite : Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the
>   current version. The backup file should be restored to a server with
>   version '14.0.0.7105' or later.

My PowerShell reports that I am at version `14.0.6029.1000`, which, if I'm correct is 2010 SP1.

I tried looking around ([here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2010/09/29/build-numbers-cube-sheet-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx)) but I just can't find out what this weird version number corresponds to. Is there any way I can find out what SP version does this correspond to?

Additionally, I have no access to the server where the backup is generated, so I can't just do something there and regenerate the backup.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7105 is the build number.

If you run Fiddler and check your current SharePoint farm, you will find in the header of your request "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6029"

In order to restore your backup, you need a farm that is beyond build 7105 (e.g. build 7106 - August 2013 CU which was released after SP2).

Comment: Got it! Upgraded to a February 2014 CU and could finally restore. Thanks